# Custom bokeh models inside notebook gives Javascript Error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to have [custom bokeh models](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) displayed inside jupyter-lab or notebooks? Currently, I get an Javascript Error when trying to do so, e.g. evaluating the [Custom Draw Tool](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/tool.html#userguide-extensions-examples-tool) example inside a notebook, bokeh will complain about:

```
Javascript Error: Model 'DrawTool' does not exist. This could be due to a widget
or a custom model not being registered before first usage.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But you will need to call `output_notebook` again (or for the first time) *after* you define the custom model. Otherwise it will not be registered with the BokehJS runtime (i.e. BokehJS will not know it exists).